# Graphql mutation with nested types?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'am having troubles with graphql input types.
I'am using react with apollo

i have this working mutation:

```
addQuestion(
question: QuestionInput!
): Question!
```

with this type:

```
type QuestionInput {
name: String!
account_id: Int!
chatbot_id: Int!
question_variants: [String!]!
answer: String!
}
```

but the problem happens with this mutation:

```
updateBranch(
id: Int!
branch: BranchInput!
): Branch!
```

with this type:

```
type BranchInput {
lead_id: Int!
title: String!
visible_order: Int!
bot_photo: String!
responses: [ResponseInput!]!
bubbles: [BubbleInput!]!
}
```

and these nested types:

```
type ResponseInput {
branch_id: Int
owner: String!
message: String!
}

type BubbleInput {
branch_id: Int
name: String!
goto: String!
}
```

the mutation works on graphql playground:

```
mutation {
  updateBranch(
    id: 2
    branch: {
      lead_id: 1
      title: "new title"
      visible_order: 1
      bot_photo: "photo"
      responses: [
        { message: "message 1", owner: "owner1" }
        { message: "message 2", owner: "owner 2" }
      ]
      bubbles: [{name: "bubble 1", goto: "link"}]
    }
  ) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

When i execute the mutation in code like this :

```
 const handleEditBranche = async (
    lead_id: number,
    title: string,
    visible_order: number,
    bot_photo: string,
    responses: {}[],
    bubbles: {}[],
    id?: string
  ) => {
    const newResponses = responses.map((response: any) => [
      { message: response.message, owner: response.owner },
    ]);
    const newBubbles = bubbles.map((bubble: any) => [
      { name: bubble.name, goto: bubble.goto },
    ]);
    console.log(id, title, visible_order, bot_photo, newResponses, newBubbles);

    await updateBranche({
      variables: {
        id,
        branch: {
          title,
          lead_id,
          visible_order,
          bot_photo,
          responses: newResponses,
          bubbles: newBubbles,
        },
      },
    });
    //setShowEdit({});
  };
```

I get this error :
[image: Error]

even though the data are correct:
[image: mutation payload]

I want to include those 2 type inside my mutation, but i don't know how.

Comment: bad payload, doubled square brackets

Comment: @xadm 
thank you, you saved me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are constructing the payload.

```
const newResponses = responses.map((response: any) => 
  { message: response.message, owner: response.owner },
);
const newBubbles = bubbles.map((bubble: any) => 
  { name: bubble.name, goto: bubble.goto },
);
console.log(id, title, visible_order, bot_photo, newResponses, newBubbles);
```

Removed the additional array for each element in `newResponses` and `newBubbles`